# How to create a formula which finds a cell that matches a range of other cells then produces a number if the cell appears.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

am having trouble with finding a suitable formula for my spreadsheet in excel.

In column A i have a list of postcodes (439 postcodes). In column B-BL i also have postcodes (these postcodes are in cells 450-onwards).

I need a formula which finds if any postcode in column A appears in another column (B-BL) and that if the postcode matches it will enter which ever number i choose to be entered in the cell next to the postcode in column A.

At the moment i am using the formula '=INDEX)$B$450@$B$482,MATCH(A#,$B$450:$B$482,0))

This formula is working however, it is only copying the postcode which appears in both columns.

Could anyone find a solution where i can make the formula enter a number instead of the postcode if the desired cell appears in another column?